# VoiceXML how to specify the way the TTS repeats a value

Tags: text-to-speech, vxml

I am having issues getting the voice browser to repeat my field value as a series of numbers rather than a large multi-digit number.  For example, my field will collect the input using type 'digits' or 'numbers' - in this case it was a transfer extension.  In the filled portion I have the collected value repeated back.  Instead of hearing extension number 2345 spoken as '2-3-4-5' it is spoken as 'two thousand three hundred fourty five'.

How can I have the value repeated sequentially?  I tried specifying a 'say-as' tag, but to no avail.  Below is the code I attempted this with:

```
<field name="extension" type="digits?length=4">
  <prompt bargein="false">
    Please dial in or say the extension of the <value expr="application.extensionValues" /> you are trying to reach.
  </prompt>
  <grammar type="application/x-nuance-gsl">
    [ dtmf-1 dtmf-2 dtmf-3 dtmf-4 dtmf-5 dtmf-6 dtmf-7 dtmf-8 dtmf-9 dtmf-0 ]
  </grammar>    
  <grammar type="application/x-nuance-gsl">
    [ one two three four five six seven eight nine ]
  </grammar>    
</field>

<filled>
  <prompt>
    I received extension number <say-as interpret-as="vxml:number"><value expr="extension"/></say-as>.  Transfering you now.
  </prompt> 
</filled>
```

**EDIT 1**

Yes the platform I am using is the "BeVocal Cafe" development enviornment. I am pointing it's IVR to a URI where I have the vxml scripts stored.

Unfortunately your suggestion did not work for me.  I attempted to change the interpret-as value to "telephone" and the interpreter did not understand and errored out.  I attempted to use "characters" which looked more like what I wanted and while there was no error, the interpreter logs stated that the interpret-as value was 'unknown'

Comment: Can you specify the platform you are using?  Especially the TTS engine.

Comment: Not sure about the TTS engine but I am using the 'BeVocal Cafe' integrated development enviornment with an externally pointed URI for the vxml script location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The say-as tag is the way to go.  Try changing interpret-as attribute to telephone:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/NOTE-ssml-sayas-20050526/#S3.3

Comment: Or http://cafe.bevocal.com/docs/vxml/index.html?content=say-as.html#287683 for bevocal.

Comment: Thank you - I had something just slightly off - 'number' not 'numbers' .. oh well :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code with the appropriate BeVocal markup.  Note that implementation of the  tag is vendor-dependent, so this is *not* portable.

```
<field name="extension" type="digits?length=4">
  <prompt bargein="false">
    Please dial in or say the extension of the <value expr="application.extensionValues" /> you are trying to reach.
  </prompt>
  <grammar type="application/x-nuance-gsl">
    [ dtmf-1 dtmf-2 dtmf-3 dtmf-4 dtmf-5 dtmf-6 dtmf-7 dtmf-8 dtmf-9 dtmf-0 ]
  </grammar>    
  <grammar type="application/x-nuance-gsl">
    [ one two three four five six seven eight nine ]
  </grammar>    
</field>

<filled>
  <prompt>
    I received extension number <say-as type="number:digits"><value expr="extension"/></say-as>.  Transfering you now.
  </prompt> 
</filled>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. But I got around it by setting the says-as type to acronym. This gets the IVR to spell out the digits one after the other. Please note that this was on PlumVoice IVR. I hope it works for you. This is your revised code.

```html
<field name="extension" type="digits?length=4">
  <prompt bargein="false">
    Please dial in or say the extension of the <value expr="application.extensionValues" /> you are trying to reach.
  </prompt>
  <grammar type="application/x-nuance-gsl">
    [ dtmf-1 dtmf-2 dtmf-3 dtmf-4 dtmf-5 dtmf-6 dtmf-7 dtmf-8 dtmf-9 dtmf-0 ]
  </grammar>    
  <grammar type="application/x-nuance-gsl">
    [ one two three four five six seven eight nine ]
  </grammar>    
</field>

<filled>
  <prompt>
    I received extension number <say-as type="acronym"><value expr="extension"/></say-as>.  Transfering you now.
  </prompt> 
</filled>
```